# How to define an extend stackpanel control with two child dependency properties

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have to write an ExtendedStackPanel control which will have two dependency properties like this.

```
<ExtendedStackPanel  IsReadOnly="{Binding Item.IsReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}"  >
     <TemplateTrue>
                         ... control visible when isreadonly is true  
      </TemplateTrue>
      <TemplateFalse>
                           ... control visible when isreadonly is false
       </TemplateFalse>
</ExtendedStackPanel>
```

I've written this to achieve the goal but it's not working.

```
public class ExtendedStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public ExtendedStackPanel()
        : base()
    {
        this.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
    }
    #region IsReadOnly
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ExtendedStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnReadOnlyChanged)));

    static void OnReadOnlyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var visible = (bool)e.NewValue;
        var control = d as ExtendedStackPanel;
        if (visible)
        {
            control.TemplateTrue.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            control.TemplateFalse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            control.TemplateTrue.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            control.TemplateFalse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
    #endregion
    #region TemplateTrue
    public Control TemplateTrue
    {
        get { return (Control)GetValue(TemplateTrueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateTrueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateTrueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateTrue", typeof(Control),
            typeof(ExtendedStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTemplateTrueChanged)));

    static void OnTemplateTrueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as ExtendedStackPanel;
        control.TemplateTrue.Visibility = control.IsReadOnly ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    #endregion
    #region TemplateFalse
    public Control TemplateFalse
    {
        get { return (Control)GetValue(TemplateFalseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateFalseProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateFalseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateFalse", typeof(Control),
            typeof(ExtendedStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTemplateFalseChanged)));

    static void OnTemplateFalseChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as ExtendedStackPanel;
        control.TemplateFalse.Visibility = !control.IsReadOnly ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my code, I have put a combobox control when IsReadOnly is set to false, and a simple textbox when IsReadOnly is set to true but nothing is displayed when code is run.
Help me please.

Comment: All this is just to select either one or the other child control, depending on the value of the bound `Item.IsReadOnly` property? Is this used in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl?

Comment: Yes. I have used a behaviour to control readonly state directly in my combobox, but when combobox is readonly, values can be changed by mouse wheeling or keybord arrows. That's why I have develop the solution above.

Comment: But why not just have a DataTemplate with a ComboBox and a TextBlock on top of each other and toggle their respective Visibility according to the items's read-only state?

Comment: Why do you want to derive from StackPanel? I don't see the necessity.

Comment: @Clemens : I want to reuse it for another controls in my xaml. The comboboxes and datepickers have the same issue.

Comment: @Martin : I will be very grateful if you have other suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Then write another DataTemplate with other controls that implements the *same pattern*: One control above another where both Visibilities are bound to the ReadOnly property, with appropriate converters to get the right Visibility value for each. If necessary these controls might themselves be containers to hold more than one child element each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I choose to use a UserControl, in which I put two ContentControl.
In code behind of the UserControl, I write this:

```
public partial class ConditionalControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ConditionalControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsReadOnly = false;
    }
    #region IsReadOnly
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ConditionalControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnReadOnlyChanged)));

    static void OnReadOnlyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var visible = (bool)e.NewValue;
        var control = d as ConditionalControl;            
        if (visible)
        {
            control.TemplateTrueContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            control.TemplateFalseContent.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            control.TemplateTrueContent.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            control.TemplateFalseContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
    #endregion
    #region TemplateFalse
    public object TemplateFalse
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TemplateFalseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateFalseProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateFalseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateFalse", typeof(object),
            typeof(ConditionalControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTemplateFalseChanged)));

    static void OnTemplateFalseChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as ConditionalControl;
        control.TemplateFalseContent.Visibility = !control.IsReadOnly ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        control.OnPropertyChanged("TemplateFalse");
    }
    #endregion
    #region TemplateTrue
    public object TemplateTrue
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TemplateTrueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateTrueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateTrueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateTrue", typeof(object),
            typeof(ConditionalControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTemplateTrueChanged)));

    static void OnTemplateTrueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as ConditionalControl;
        control.TemplateTrueContent.Visibility = control.IsReadOnly ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        control.OnPropertyChanged("TemplateTrue");
    }
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "TemplateFalse")
        {
            this.TemplateFalseContent.Content = this.TemplateFalse;
        }
        if (propertyName == "TemplateTrue")
        {
            this.TemplateTrueContent.Content = this.TemplateTrue;
        }
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.